# number not printing only [] is coming in text file

Tags: java

In the below code the questions, answers i enter in jsp form are entered in text file. But infront of it number must be printed

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.io.*" errorPage="" %>
<%

         /* String num=request.getParameter("qnum");
    session.setAttribute("quesnum",num);*/

    String q=request.getParameter("qn");
    session.setAttribute("question",q);

    String opt1=request.getParameter("A");
    session.setAttribute("a",opt1);

    String opt2=request.getParameter("B");
    session.setAttribute("b",opt2);

    String opt3=request.getParameter("C");
    session.setAttribute("c",opt3);

    String opt4=request.getParameter("D");
    session.setAttribute("d",opt4);

    String ans=request.getParameter("ANS");
    session.setAttribute("answer",ans);


%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Text File</title>
</head>

<body>
<%



File f=new File("D:\\Program Files\\Tomcat 6.0\\webapps\\ROOT\\tst.txt");
f.createNewFile();
try
{

BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));

    int num=1;

   bw.newLine();
 while(num<100)
   {  

        bw.write((char)num);
        bw.write("|");
    bw.write(q);

        bw.write("|");
    bw.write(opt1);

        bw.write("|");
    bw.write(opt2);

        bw.write("|");
    bw.write(opt3);

        bw.write("|");
    bw.write(opt4);

        bw.write("|");
        bw.write(ans);

        bw.flush();


bw.close();
}

num++;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
%>

</body>
</html>

Output must be 
1|quest1|option a |option b|option c|option d| and:a
2|quest2|option a |option b|option c|option d| and:b
3|quest3|option a |option b|option c|option d| and:d

but instead of 1 2 3 i get 
 []|quest1|option a |option b|option c|option d| and:a
```

[] symbol is coming in text file. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting the `int`numbers from 1 to 100 to `char` as byte-values. This is probably not what you want, because this is - assuming western languages - equivalent to the ASCII table from the beginning on. The first 32 or so characters are non-printable stuff like Linefeeds, Beeps etc. which apparently do not make it into your output.

So instead of

```
bw.write((char)i);
```

you need to convert your int into a String, e. g. like so:

```
bw.write(String.valueOf(i));
```

Comment: thank u it works fine but next time when i enter 2nd question, it still displays 1 !!!!!

Comment: That is because you start counting for each incoming request by setting num to 1. You will need to keep a counter that spans across requests. If this number is to be kept per session, you might store it there and increase for each request.

Comment: @Sumithra - sure, what else do you expect - you set `num` to 1 each time. If you want to incremented numbers, then you'll have to read the last used number from the file first, increment it and use it as the value for `num`. (And remove the "while" loop, it's obsolete)

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
bw.write((char)num);
```

you're converting the number (e.g. 1) to a char but you want the number printed as a string:

```
bw.write(String.valueOf(num));
```

is a simple solution.

```
bw.write(String.format("%d", i));
```

is slightly better as is allows formatting of the numbers (alignment, leading zeros, ...)